# rails each iterator iterating two times

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get some nested queries to get some objects. Here is some of the code

stream_controller.rb

```
def show
  @rank = Rank.where(user_id: Application.where(stream_id: @stream.id))
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% i = 1 %>
<% @rank.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i %></td>
    <td><%= f.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= User.find(f.user_id.to_i).name %></td>
    <td><%= f.rank %></td>
  <tr><br>
  <% i += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is the output is:

```
Sr  User id     Name    Rank
1   15  a16 2
2   7   a7 a71  4
3   8   a8 a81  6
4   13  a14 a41 8
5   1   a1  13
6   4   sm  14
7   15  a16 2
8   7   a7 a71  4
9   8   a8 a81  6
10  13  a14 a41 8
11  1   a1  13
12  4   sm  14
```

That is its iterating two time why is that happening ? and how can it be prevented?

Comment: I just edited your html to make it more readable.  Can you say what you'd expect to see in the first row for example?

Comment: You use a lot of `where` calls where you could just use associations.  Eg instead of `User.find(f.user_id.to_i).name ` can you not do `f.user.name`?

Comment: And your variable naming is really confusing:  if `@rank` is a collection of Rank objects why not call it `@ranks` instead of `@rank`?  And then when you iterate over it, you refer to each member as `f` (why??) and then to make it even more confusing you say `f.rank` in the loop!  Does the "Rank" class have a "rank"  instance method?

Comment: Why are you so sure that something is iterating twice as opposed to there being multiple rank objects per user id ?

Comment: @Federick I am not sure but the pattern is with different stream id

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but your code could be tidied up quite a bit.  Here's a nicer way to do your loop:  since `@rank` is a collection variable i've renamed it to `@ranks` in keeping with convention.

```
<% @ranks.each_with_index do |rank, i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
    <td><%= rank.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= rank.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= rank.rank %></td>
  <tr><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would add a `.includes(:user)` to prevent from `n+1` queries and eager-load the users

Comment: I was going to try to rewrite the controller code too but it's unclear to me what the schema is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@rank = Rank.where(user_id: Application.where(stream_id: @stream.id)).uniq
```

The .uniq (at the end of the line) will remove any duplicate rows returned by your query.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sql statement and it solved my problem and put in model file and called it from controller on button click it solved my problem

```
def self.generate_result(stream_id)
sql = "select distinct user_id, rank from ranks where
       user_id = any(
       select user_id from applications where stream_id =
       #{stream_id}
       and verified = true)
       order by rank asc"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

end

Comment: The Rank.where(user_id: Application.where(stream_id: @stream.id)) is not generating me the required sql